# What would be the minimal setup of IntegrationTest configuration in sbt 0.13.x?

Tags: sbt

I've the following `build.sbt`:

```
name := "it-config-sbt-project"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

Defaults.itSettings

lazy val `it-config-sbt-project` = project.in(file(".")).configs(IntegrationTest)
```

How could I make the line where I add [the IntegrationTest configuration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing#integration-tests) even simpler?

I would *rather* like to have a setting with current configurations and settings of the project, e.g.

```
settings ++= Defaults.itSettings

configs += IntegrationTest
```

or even have the `itSettings` settings applied automatically with the following line in the sbt file:

```
configs += IntegrationTest
```

Comment: I don't think a better way is currently available, but I hope to learn that I am wrong.

Comment: There's a better way, but not much - use `project in file(".") configs(IntegrationTest)`.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski your shorter version didn't work for me: `found: sbt.Project required: sbt.Def.SettingsDefinition`

Comment: @Caoilte are you using sbt 0.13+? Seems so given the message. Did you use `lazy val `it-config-sbt-project` = project in file(".") configs IntegrationTest`? What's your whole `build.sbt`?

Comment: I did use lazy val as in your OP and that works fine. I thought you were suggesting in your later comment that the lazy val wasn't needed, whereas actually I think you were pointing out that the brackets were optional.

Comment: This is by the far the simplest I've ever seen, I can't remember how I first stumbled upon this but wish it was referenced in more places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sbt needs to know the configurations for delegation before evaluating settings.  So, configurations can't be defined inside the settings system.

Note that if using a configuration that doesn't `extend` another configuration, it isn't strictly necessary to register it on the Project with the `configs` method though.

Answer (score 5):

I found myself similarly frustrated. The best solution I have found is to borrow from Josh Suereth's [Effective SBT slides](http://jsuereth.com/scala/2013/06/11/effective-sbt.html) and create a project helper function that adds the IntegrationTest configuration for you.

eg

```
object BasePlugin extends Plugin {
  val baseSettings = Defaults.itSettings

  def baseProject(name: String, location: String = "."): Project = (
    Project(name, file(location)) configs(IntegrationTest)
  )
}
```

I pull this and a bunch of other settings in as a plugin and then my build.sbt is as simple as

```
import caoilte.BasePlugin

BasePlugin.baseSettings

val helloWorld = BasePlugin.baseProject("helloWorld")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using SBT 0.13 as you have your project definition inside .sbt file.

There is a new feature called autoSetting that you can use to influence the combined .sbt settings from multiple sbt files.

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Community/ChangeSummary_0.13.0.html#control-over-automatically-added-settings

An example will be:

```
lazy val `it-config-sbt-project` = project.in(file("."))
  .autoSettings(userSettings, allPlugins, sbtFiles(file("../mysetting.sbt")), defaultSbtFiles)
```