# Why are integration tests in a Play/Scala project not executed when using "sbt it:test"?

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.3

I have a [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) 2.3 project in which I'd like to separate unit tests and functional tests as follows:

1. running `sbt test` should run unit tests and exclude integration tests
2. running `sbt it:test` should run integration tests only

The Scala documentation suggests using `project/Build.scala`, but I'd like to use combination of `build.sbt` and `project/Build.scala`, so my configuration looks like this (I have also tried putting all of configuration into `Build.scala`):

**build.sbt**

```
....

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.2.3",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.5" % "it, test",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.5" % "it, test"
)

def funTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = ((name endsWith "ItTest") || (name endsWith "IntegrationTest"))
def unitTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = ((name endsWith "Test") && !funTestFilter(name))

testOptions in IntegrationTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(funTestFilter))

testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Filter(unitTestFilter))
```

**project/Build.scala**

```
import sbt._

object Build extends Build {

  lazy val root =
    Project("root", file("."))
      .configs( IntegrationTest )
      .settings( Defaults.itSettings : _* )

}
```

Under this configuration running `sbt test` does exclude my integration test (which ends with `IntegrationTest`) but running `sbt it:test` finds no tests.

The article suggests putting files in a specific path, but I don't know what the equivalent path is for the Play project.

The standard source hierarchy is used:

```
src/it/scala for Scala sources
src/it/java for Java sources
src/it/resources for resources that should go on the integration test classpath
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The first part - about setting up integration tests in `build.sbt` - is described in another question [What would be the minimal setup of IntegrationTest configuration in sbt 0.13.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19506136/1305344) -- it boils down to the following entries in `build.sbt`:

```
Defaults.itSettings

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).configs(IntegrationTest)
```

Since a Play project is defined as follows:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

you should add `configs` and you're done.

```
lazy val root = project in file(".") enablePlugins(PlayScala) configs(IntegrationTest)
```

Do `reload` or restart the sbt/activator session and execute `it:test`.

```
[it-play] $ it:test
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/it-play/}root...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Sep 13, 2014 7:12:27 PM
```

As to the place where the integration tests should go in a Play project, the short answer is do `show it:sourceDirectory` in the shell, i.e. `src/it` with `scala`, `java` and `resources` directories beneath to contain respective sources.

Add test framework library in `it` configuration, i.e. in `build.sbt` there should be something similar to - note the `it` configuration:

```
"org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.4.2" % "it"
```

Do `reload` the sbt session or restart it, and `it:test` should work with Specs2 tests for all tests under `src/it/scala`.

To narrow what tests should be executed, add your filter - make sure it's after the line with `Defaults.itSettings` as the order does matter and one can override the other:

```
val funTestFilter: String => Boolean = { name =>
  (name endsWith "ItTest") || (name endsWith "IntegrationTest")
}

testOptions in IntegrationTest += Tests.Filter(funTestFilter)
```

Do `reload` or restart sbt and execute `it:test`. It should work. Do `show it:testOptions` to ensure your setup's loaded properly:

```
[it-play] $ show it:testOptions
[info] List(Filter(<function1>))
```

The entire `build.sbt` that worked for me is as follows - it's created by `activator new it-play play-scala`:

```
name := """it-play"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = project in file(".") enablePlugins(PlayScala) configs(IntegrationTest)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.4.2" % "it"
)

Defaults.itSettings

val funTestFilter: String => Boolean = { name =>
  (name endsWith "ItTest") || (name endsWith "IntegrationTest")
}

testOptions in IntegrationTest += Tests.Filter(funTestFilter)
```

Comment: Thanks!!!.  My project doesn't know what "PlayScala" is, this is the error I get: "/web/api-checkout/build.sbt:28: error: not found: value PlayScala", however, it seems to work without it, I don't know what problems that might cause otherwise, I have not found any issues yet.

Comment: Using Play 2.3.9, I followed the examples but my IntegrationSpec.scala cannot compile because it cannot find PlaySpecification i.e. class IntegrationSpec extends PlaySpecification. Any idea why SBT didn't include play libs to "it" phase? Also, I have added this to build.sbt,
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.5" % "it, test",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-junit" % "3.5" % "it, test",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-mock" % "3.5" % "it, test" 
Thanks

Comment: ok I added play-test to "it" i.e. "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-test" % "2.3.9" % "it"

Comment: It's confusing that Play's integration test is "src/it" instead of "/it", because it would make more sense if it were alongside "/app" and "/test" in the base directory, as per [the Play Anatomy](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Anatomy).  I moved my integration tests there by changing the setting in `build.sbt` to read `sourceDirectory in IntegrationTest :=  baseDirectory.value / "it"`.  Then it finds the usual `it/java`, `it/scala`, `it/resources` directories.

Comment: That is quite strange naming suggestions - with a case insensitive match, `UnitTest` also ends with `ItTest`, and the fact that `ItTest` resolves to `IntegrationTestTest` ;-)

Answer (score 13):

This is what I ended up doing, which allows me to:

1. keep my integration tests in play's `/test` directory
2. run `sbt test` for Unit Tests and `sbt fun:test` for functional/integration tests

Here is the `build.sbt`, no need for a `project/Build.scala`

> ```
> libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
>   ...
>   "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.2.3",
>   "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.5" % "test",
>   "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.5" % "test"
> )
>
> lazy val FunTest = config("fun") extend(Test)
>
> def funTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = ((name endsWith "ItTest") || (name endsWith "IntegrationTest"))
> def unitTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = ((name endsWith "Test") && !funTestFilter(name))
>
> lazy val root = project in file(".") configs(FunTest) settings( inConfig(FunTest)(Defaults.testTasks) : _*)
>
> testOptions in FunTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(funTestFilter))
>
> testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Filter(unitTestFilter))
> ```

Comment: I really like this solution because I can just clone and go in any IDE of choice. If I create a new testing folder then as of today I have to either put IDE specific stuff in my build (ick) or have an extra IDE step to tell the IDE about my new folder (not great either).